# Как использовать битовую маску в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хотелось бы в поле писать несколько параметров. Например 10 - это 1- виден 0 - включен. Т.е. это можно записать в десятичной форме как 2

Как быть в срезе с БД? Вот на C# можно логически умножить на номер бита, а в случае с запросом как быть

Comment: Хочу вас предупредеить, что битовые маски нельзя использовать с индексами [в MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5352435/2156062). В PostgreSQL это возможно сделать, но на каждый вариант маски необходимо завести [частичный индекс](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227018/2156062). Если требуется хранить несколько фиксированных состояний, то можно ограничется нарастащей последовательностью. К примеру, 0 - 
DELETED, 1 - BLOCKED, 2 - ACTIVE. Таким набором можно манипулировать знаками сравнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть другой вариант

```
select (10 & 2) // Выдаст 0 или 2
```

если нужно что бы одновременно было 0110 (в дес. 6) тогда

```
select (10 & 6)  // Выдаст 0 или 6
```

полный пример так

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE (pole & 6) = 6
```

Comment: так я путаться начал. SELECT  (51 & 16) отдаст 16 (51 - 0011 0011, 16 - 0001 0000) то есть при любом частичном пересечении не 0. а как тогда точно узнать что именно 3 и 4 бит указаны, а не только 4

Comment: я же в примере показал, если 60=11 1100 и 12=1100 (тут 12 это 4й и 3й бит) будет select (60 & 12) если ответ 12 значит оба бита совпадают

Comment: 51 & -112 - ответ 16. то если ответ не совпадает с вопросом, то как минимум одно вхождение, если 0 то нет совпадений, если совпадает - то все вхождения

Comment: @des1roer да правильно сказали

Answer (score 0):

Не думал что это такой сложный вопрос

```
  select get_bit(10::bit(4), 2)
```

Т.е. `10::bit(4)` приведет вопрос к двоичному виду 1010

а 2 - это это номер бита (отсчет слева направо, от нуля)